# conectarse a localhost desde un dispositivo que se encuentre en la misma red uso XAMPP

Tags: xampp

Bueno hola amigos de la comunidad queriero saber como activar la conexion remota de Xampp para conectar de un dipositivo mobil eh echo lo que mucho foro dice

- cambiando el puerto de 80 a 8080
- en el archivo httpd-xampp.conf lo eh  agregado al final este codigo

```html
    #
# New XAMPP security concept
#
# Close XAMPP security section here
<LocationMatch “^/(?i:(?:security))”>
Order deny,allow
#Deny from all
#Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8
Allow from all
ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
# Close XAMPP sites here
<LocationMatch “^/(?i:(?:xampp|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))”>
Order deny,allow
#Deny from all
#Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8
Allow from all
ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

- eh desactivado el antivirus y el firewall
- en el navegador pongo mi ip seguido de el nombre mi aplicacion o xampp

en el navegador me manda este este error

```html
Not Found

HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.
```

Ayuda le agradesco de antemano

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con cambiar el IP de 80 a 8080? El rango de una IP va de 1 a 256, el ingresar algo como 8080 es **totalmente** incorrecto. ¿No te estarás refiriendo al puerto?

Comment: correcto es el puerto 8080  sin ese puerto no me funciona el localhost

Comment: Por defecto XAMPP permite la conexión remota dentro de la misma red local para las aplicaciones web, en donde se hay que configurar es cuando hay que acceder a phpMyAdmin. El puerto por default para **http** es el 80, te recomendaría no lo cambies. Prueba enviando un **ping** desde el **cmd** la máquina cliente, utilizando la IP de la máquina servidor por ejemplo: `ping 192.168.1.70` para verificar si existe conexión de red. Es importante especifiques la versión de XAMPP y sus IP dentro de la red.

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres hacer es conectarte desde un dispositivo mobil(por ej. una tableta) a tu aplicacion web, simplemente tienes que poner la direccion ip de la PC donde esta alojada tu aplicacion.

Ejemplo: en el navegador del dispositivo tendrias que poner una direccion similar a esta:

```
http://192.168.1.2/miaplicacion.php
```

Si cambiaste el puerto agregaselo al final.

```
http://192.168.1.2/miaplicacion.php:8080
```

En tu caso tendrias que cambiar la parte de:

```
192.168.1.2
```

por la direccion ip de la PC que tiene alojada tu a aplicacion.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias bro  la unica diferencia es que  el puerto 8080 se lo puse al principio despues del ip seguido dos punto luego el puerto 8080

Comment: @Josue, La forma correcta es  http ://192.168.1.2:8080/miaplicacion.php  o sea http ://ip:puerto

Answer (score 0):

para encontrar tu localhost desde un emulador o un dispositivo, lo mas correctos es así,
si usas xamp, observa en que puerto esta corriendo puede ser 80, 8080, 443....... en el puerto que este lo agrega al final de tu ip y luego tu dirección de localhost, en tu caso seria así http://192.168.1.2:8080/miaplicacion.php

hago este comentario luego de tanto tiempo, por si alguna persona, le sucede lo mismo en la actualidad

suerte